# Question about number of perfect squares between two perfect cubes

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for a natural number $k≥2$ , there are a minimum of two perfect squares in the interval $(k^3,(k+1)^3)$

I tried induction , supposing that there are $m^2<n^2$ in the interval , and to prove that there exists two perfect squares $q^2<r^2$ in $((k+1)^3,(k+2)^3))$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help.

Comment: As a hint to get started:  can you prove that there is at least one perfect square in the interval?

Comment: Yes , I think it's $([\sqrt{k^3}]^2)$

Comment: Hint: for $k\ge 2$, $(k+1)^{3/2}-k^{3/2}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{k}>2$.

Comment: So there are at least two integers between $(k+1)^\frac{3}{2} - k^\frac{3}{2}$ or

Answer (score 0):

Let $m$ be the largest integer such that $m^2\le k^3$

$m\le k^{\frac 32}$

if $k>1$

$4m \le 4k^{\frac 32} < 3k^2$ and $4<3k+1$

$k^3<(m+1)^2<(m+2)^2  = m^2 + 4m + 4 < k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 = (k+1)^3$